# Sharepoint 2010 - Custom List - Make Column Item clickable and editable

Tags: list, sharepoint, clickable

I created a custom list with two columns: Name and City.

I want to make the items in column City clickable. Meaning, if I click on item 'Chicago' the view item form directly pops up which is usually accessible via "View Item".

I have seen this before, but don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

SharePoint allows you to do this with the `Title` column, which is a default column for any list. What you want to do is set up your list and reuse the "Title" column for your "City" column. This is as simple as going to your List Settings screen and renaming the column (from the List Settings screen, click the "Title" column, then change the Column Name to "City" and save your changes).

Next, set up a view for your list (modify the default one or create a new one). On the Edit View screen, one of your column choices will be "City (linked to item with edit menu)". Make sure that column is included in your view and you should have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi For opening the view list details from the city ..You have to open the list view webpart in sharepoint designer select the list item from where you want to enable your view details right click there and tick the option for linking ti the list .